# Ruby EBCDIC conversion with String#encode instead of iconv

Tags: ruby, encode, iconv, ebcdic

I used to do it fine with:

```
Iconv.iconv('ASCII', 'EBCDIC-US', someEBCDICstring)
```

since ruby 1.9 I get that warning:

```
iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
```

but I can't find any reference of EBCDIC or cp37, cp500, cp875... in the Encoding class:

```
p Encoding.name_list
```

Am I supposed to import it from somewhere? Can I add it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the gem - https://rubygems.org/gems/iconv

(And here are the docs - http://rubydoc.info/gems/iconv/1.0.3/frames)

Answer (score 1):

In [Ruby 2.3 the EBCDIC-encoding is added](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/NEWS-2_3_0.html):

> Encoding
>
> new Encoding::IBM037 (alias ebcdic-cp-us; dummy)

So this should work:

```
str = 'xx'
str.encode('IBM037')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'iconv' # sudo apt-get install ruby-dev && sudo gem install iconv
```

This works for me...

```
# set up translation to EBCDIC
trsl = Iconv.new('EBCDIC-US','ASCII')

# translate value
ebcdic = trsl.iconv(somestring)
```